# Search backward on MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have 2 collection.

Collection "users"

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b00098e0fdb6634b1f54e6"),
        "state" : "active",
        "backends" : [
                DBRef("backends", ObjectId("54b001ebe0fd853df1c93419")),
                DBRef("backends", ObjectId("54b00284e0fd853df1c9341b"))
        ]
}
```

Collection "backends"

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b001ebe0fd853df1c93419"),
        "state" : "running"
}
```

I want to get a list of backend of a user where the backend's state is "running".
How can mongodb do this like join two table?
Is it any method to search backward from backend or have function the filter?

I can search like this

```
db.users.find({"backends.$id" : "distring"})
```

But what if I want to search the state inside backend object? like.

```
db.users.find({"backends.$state" : "running"})
```

But ofcoure it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support joins so you need to do this in two steps. In the shell:

```js
var ids = db.backends.find({state: 'running'}, {_id: 1}).map(function(backend) {
    return backend._id;
});

var users = db.users.find({'backends.$id': {$in: ids}}).toArray();
```

On a side note, you're probably better off using a plain `ObjectId` instead of a `DBRef` for the `backends` array elements unless the ids in that array can actually refer to docs in multiple collections.